# SQL Server 3 table call

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, relational-database, primary-key

I have this
[image: Here are my tables]

Imagine like `Localidades = States`, and you have all states from USA, then you have Barrios that have a city, and you want to insert an 'Inmueble' that is in a city, and you want to select all 'inmuebles' that are in (example) California.

Sorry for my English. I'm just starting with SQL and .NET. I tried for a long time to solve this solution but couldn't. I just tried something like:

```
select * 
from Inmuebles 
join Barrios 
on Inmuebles.Localidad = Barrios.Barrio 
join Localidades 
on Barrio.Localidad = Localidades.Id 
where Localidad = 'Capital Federal'
```

Comment: Other than the issue of an ambiguous column in the WHERE statement (you should be specifying which table you want for the "Localidad" column), what exactly is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

From the look of it, Localidad will be the Id in Localidades.Id and I guess that that would be an int. You want the description to be the Localadades description, which might be Localidades.Zone? If so then use:

```
where localidades.Zone = 'Capital Federal' -- or 'California' or whatever
```